# Decomposition of the tangent space of a manifold with inner product

Tags: riemannian-geometry, direct-sum, submanifold

I'm reading about isometric immersions in the Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry and there he states that if $f: M^n \longrightarrow \overline{M}^{n+m=k}$ is an immersion and $\overline{M}$ endowed with an inner product, then we can splits $T_p \overline{M}$ into the direct sum

$$T_p \overline{M} = T_p M \oplus \left( T_p M \right)^{\perp},$$

where $\left( T_p M \right)^{\perp}$ is the orthogonal complement of $T_p M$ in $T_p \overline{M}$.

My doubt is why is valid? I know from Linear Algebra that if $V$ is a vectorial space with dimension $n$ and $U \subset V$ is a subspace of $V$, then it's possible write $V = U \oplus U^{\perp}$, but $T_p M$ is not necessarily a subspace of $T_p \overline{M}$, so why we can decompose $T_p \overline{M}$ in a direct sum of $T_p M$ and $\left( T_p M \right)^{\perp}$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T_p M$ is naturally identified with a subspace of $T_{f(p)} \overline M$ via the map $Tf\colon T_p M \to T_{f(p)} \overline M$.  Here $Tf$ is injective on $T_p M$ because $f$ is required to be an immersion.